# Hooking after blog info update

Tags: hooks

I've been unsuccesfully looking for a way to hook into the "site information" update action. With "site information update", I mean when the blog's admin changes its title, description, etc. Does such thing exist?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would [`wp_update_site`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_update_site/) be the hook you're looking for?

Comment: Yes Pat J, lots of thanks ;)